# How to import scss module once for the hole react app?

Tags: reactjs, sass

so this is my folder structure

```
src/
├── Components
│   ├── App
│   │   ├── App.js
│   │   └── App.scss
│   └── Homepage
│       ├── Homepage.js
│       └── Homepage.scss
├── index.js
└── styles
    ├── _buttons.scss
    ├── _config.scss
    └── index.css
```

In the styles directory, I have some commonly used css, and I import all modules inside the App.js component using `@import`.
The problem is that I have to include them again in the Homepage.js component.
Is there a way to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Create a file `_main.scss` and import every other styling file in there.

```
@import './Components/App/App.scss';
@import './Components/Homepage/Homepage.scss';
@import './styles/_buttons.scss';
...
```

Edit:
Import the `_main.scss` file in the `.js` files wherever you need to.
You can also create different files according to what you need.
For example:

`_for_components.scss`

```
@import './styles/_buttons.scss';
@import './styles/_config.scss';
@import './styles/index.css';
```

`_for_styles.scss`

```
@import './Components/App/App.scss';
@import './Components/Homepage/Homepage.scss';
```